# Scope of variable when overloading methods

Tags: java

For instance,

```
class ClassOne{

int y = 3
int x = 2

void foo(){
--y;
}
void bar(){
y--;
}
void tesla(){
int y = 10;
}
}
```

As far as I understand, methods will change class variables in that way:

1. `foo()` will do nothing on either variables
2. `bar()` will decrease y var by 1, so `y=2`
3. `tesla()` will create private or protected variable y which can be accessible only inside this `tesla()` method.

I am not sure about third one, please comment, did I understand it right?

Comment: `foo()` and `bar()` have the same effect on y, while `tesla` has its own local variable.

Comment: A good reason not to confuse member *fields* with *local variables*. They have different names (as well as different scopes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `foo` and `bar` will decrement the objects `y` variable by one - thus achieve the same effect. `tesla` will create a local variable `y` for that method. You will probably get a warning.

Comment: What is the difference between --y and y-- ? When I should use --y and when y-- ?

Comment: The difference is the order of execution. `--y` decreases first and evaluates `y` then, `y--` evaluates y first and decreases then. I your case it doesn't matter, it does, however, matter when calling functions like `DoSomething(--y)`. This decreases y and passes the decreased value to `DoSomething`. Calling `DoSomething(y--)` calls `DoSomething` with the value of y and then decreases y.

Comment: The difference is when you use it in the RHS of an express.i.e. if y is 5 the k = y--; will set k to 5 and y will become 4, whilst k=--y; will set k to 4 and y to 4. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's right.  But giving a local variable the same name as a member variable is something you should never do - it just makes your code way too confusing.

Comment: I meant to say, you're right about point 3.  Of course, point 1 is wrong - `foo()` will decrease `y`, just like `bar()` does.